# How to store complex objects in javascript database? [JSON.stringify() leads to errors]

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a class called Player. I also have a list of players called gameData. 
I want to store gameData in a database so user data isn't reset every time the bot restarts / crashes.

When I try JSON.stringify(gameData); it results in an error. I think this is Discord's fault.

[image]

Here is the constructor for Player, let me know if you want to see more.

```
constructor(namein, rolein, abilityin, playerObjin, memberIn) {
        this.name = namein;
        this.alive = true;
        this.role = rolein;
        this.ability = abilityin;
        this.hasPerformedAction = true;
        this.targetObject = null;
        this.target = "none";
        this.playerObject = playerObjin; // msg.author
        this.memberObject = memberIn; // msg.member
        this.selfHealed = false;
        this.visitedBy = [];
        this.voteSelection = null;
        this.guiltyOrInno = 0;
        this.score = 0;
        this.beenVotedUpBy = [];

    }
```

namein, rolein, abilityin are all strings

What I am looking for: a way to store and access gameData that is persistent through runs.

Comment: Teh object you are stringifying has a circular reference. remove it before stringifying.

Comment: @KevinB I cannot. The class User is created by discord, not me. My post said that I was looking for a way to store the data without using JSON.

Comment: that's not true at all. If you can stringify it and get a circular reference error, you can move what you want from it to an object without a circular reference and store it. You'll of course have to turn it back into an instance later if that's important to you.

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that playerObjin, or memberIn, has a reference to this object that you are trying to stringify, or one of those objects has a reference to the other. you cannot do circular references in JSON, where one of your properties contains a reference to another of your properties, anywhere at all down the line.

Comment: is there a different way to store complex objects besides JSON? there is nothing i can do to fix that circular reference (it is discord's code, not mine)

Comment: @nothing but you have access to the data, in order to turn it into JSON, right? so you can manipulate the data before saving, then re-manipulate the data after turning it back into an object. Take out the circular reference, save, then when you load, re-add the circular reference.

Comment: @nothing imagine trying to store the circular reference as text. you write out each of the properties of Object A as text, and one of those properties is Object B, so you write out all of the properties of Object B as text, and one of those properties is Object A, so then you write out all of the properties of Object A again, etc etc for infinite levels back and forth.